# Write inside in editable div which is inside an iframe

Tags: java, html, iframe, selenium-webdriver

After switching to `iframe`

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='ContentFrame']")));
```

I have tried these two ways but none is working.

**Actions:**

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(locator);
        action().moveToElement(webElement); 
        action().click();
        action().sendKeys("Hello world");
        action().build().perform();
```

**JS Executor**

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(locator);
        String script = "arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'Hello world');";
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(script, webElement);
```

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="ContentFrame" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="/content/geometrixx/assdasasda.html" style="height: 603px;">
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class=" aem-AuthorLayer-Edit" style="overflow: hidden;">
      <head>
      <body class="page homepage " spellcheck="false">
           <div class="parbase clientcontext">
           <div id="main_bg" class="bg">
               <div class="header">
               <div id="main">
                   <div class="container_16">
                        <div class="grid_16">
                        <div class="grid_12 body_container">
                             <div class="lead">
                             <div class="par parsys">
                                   <div class="section text parbase is-edited gecko" contenteditable="true" style="outline-style: none;">
                                   <p>Hello World</p>
```

Comment: Have you tried simply send keys without using `Actions`? `webElement.sendKeys("Hello world");`. Sometimes the simplest ways work best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write inside a frame, you need to click on the `framebody` and then you can write whatever you want to.

**Method1**

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='ContentFrame']")));
WebElement framebody = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
new Actions(driver).click(framebody).sendKeys("Hello World!").build().perform();
```

**Method2**

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@id='ContentFrame']")));
WebElement framebody = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
framebody.sendKeys("HelloWorld!");
```

Hopefully it should work.

Comment: it worked. But if I want to verify this text "Hello World!" or click on it. I tried first clicking the `framebody` and then clicking text like this `....By.xpath("//div[@class='text cq-dd-image']/p[contains(text(),'Hello World!')]")).click();` but it doesnt work and gives error some other element received click. I can't see it in firepath(because it is inside same iframe) but it can be seen in HTML console.